# Palindrome String Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, string

While trying to check Palindrome String getting this error"String Index out of bound -1"

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    String s= "Madam";
    String Temp=s;
    String k=new String();
    //System.out.println(s.length());
    int m=s.length();

    for (int i=5;i>=m;m--) {
        System.out.println(m);
        String t=String.valueOf(s.charAt(m-1) ) ;
        k=k+t;
        System.out.println(k);
    }

    System.out.println(k);

    if (k==Temp) {
        System.out.println("String is Palindrome"+" "+k);   
    } else {
        System.out.println("String is not Palindrome"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the equality with `equals()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop you want to use `i`, but dealing with `m`. Even you are decreasing `m`.  Whenever m is decreased to 0, `s.charAt(m-1)` is trying to find character in negative position of the string. As a result, you are getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. So, instead of

```
for (int i=5;i>=m;m--) {
    System.out.println(m);
    String t=String.valueOf(s.charAt(m-1) ) ;
    k=k+t;
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

It should be:

```
for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    String t = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)) ;
    k=k+t;
    System.out.println(k);
}
```

Simply the code could be:

```
String s = "Madam", reverse = "";
int m = s.length();

for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reverse += s.charAt(i);
}
System.out.println(reverse);

if (reverse.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) { // don't use '==' for checking equality of strings
    System.out.println(s + " is Palindrome");
} else {
    System.out.println(s + " is not Palindrome");
}
```

Comment: Thanks "For Loop" worked perfect. I not only improved my code but learned the other and better way of coding it too.Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
for (int i=5;i>=m;m--)
```

with this

```
for (int i=s.length();i>0;i--)  
String t=String.valueOf(s.charAt(i-1) ) ;
```

because length of string is 5 in this case and then index range is 0-4 in this case and you are also accessing 0 index which will give you -1 at this place `s.charAt(m-1)` so don't traverse 0 index. plus there should be `i--` with decrement operator instead of `m--`

or one line code can also be as

```
System.out.println(s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()));
// this will give you boolean result with True or False
// which can be used with conditional statements to make thing concise and clean
```

but this will not too efficient when string is considerably very large

Comment: Exception "String index out of range: 5 " its giving this exception .This works fine "for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; i--) "

Comment: The `StringBuilder` approach will definitely be more efficient than calling `String.valueOf`, followed by string concatenation *for each character*. You can make it even more efficient using `s.contentEquals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse())`, unfortunately, it doesn’t work with upper case letter at the beginning like in the OP’s example. By the way, don’t use abbreviations like `S.o.p`. You save a few seconds of typing at the expense of confusing the target audience (especially newbies).

Comment: @Holger `StringBuilder` is better though i meant that there can be better solutions when string becomes too large but some newbie don;t like algos and about `S.o.p` i actually knew this at my earlier stage so i thought i could have a single line leverage although i shouldn't have.thanks for pointing this out and for your time too.